# Styled-components w/ Typescript: missing type for theme variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

The `theme` variable got the `any` type just on the top-level. If I'm using `theme` at a `css''` block it got the correct typing `DefaultTheme`.

Example:

```
const Header = styled.div<{ invertedColor: boolean }>`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.blue}; // theme = any

  ${({ invertedColor }) =>
    invertedColor &&
    css`
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.white}; // theme = DefaultTheme (correct)
    `}
`
```

Also `<{ invertedColor: boolean }>` is not working since `invertedColor` is `any` here.

I've added a `styled-components.d.ts` with the following content:

```
import 'styled-components';

type ColorType = 'blue' | 'white';

declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    color: Record<ColorType, string>;
  }
}
```

Using the following versions:

```
"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.22",
"styled-components": "^5.3.3",
```

I've tried to debug & check where the type is lost because its correctly passed at the `ThemeProvider` - also tried every solution from here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1589

What's the best way to debug that? Any hint?

Comment: This is a weird one.  I'm not able to reproduce what you were seeing where you got `any` in `styled` but `DefaultTheme` in `css`. When I put your declarations into a separate `styled-component.d.ts` file I got `any` for both (probably my CodeSandbox is not configured correctly to find/read that file).  But when I copy and pasted your `declare module` into the same file as the `Header` I am seeing `DefaultTheme` on both. https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lucy-0un2kj?file=/src/App.tsx Same in TS Playground https://tsplay.dev/NlgjOw

Comment: @Aaroniker you may need to further specify details of your exact issue (e.g. exact versions of styled-components and its types), as it looks like other people are unable to reproduce it precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Weird that you're having `any` for your theme typing.

I'm doing it in a close but different way:

`styled-component.d.ts`

```
// import original module declarations
import 'styled-components';
import { ITheme } from './styles/theme';

// and extend them!
declare module 'styled-components' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface DefaultTheme extends ITheme {}
}
```

I'm extending `DefaultTheme` with my `ITheme` object, which is something like that:

```
import {
  borderRadius,
  boxShadows,
  IBorderRadius,
  IBoxShadows,
  ITransitions,
  IZIndexes,
  transitions,
  zIndexes,
} from './base';
import { colors, IColors } from './colors';
import { ISizes, sizes } from './sizes';

export interface ITheme {
  colors: IColors;
  sizes: ISizes;
  boxShadows: IBoxShadows;
  zIndexes: IZIndexes;
  borderRadius: IBorderRadius;
  transitions: ITransitions;
}

export const Theme: ITheme = {
  colors,
  sizes,
  boxShadows,
  zIndexes,
  borderRadius,
  transitions,
};
```

And I'm using `<ThemeProvider>` from `import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';`

```
<ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
```

I'm using nearly the same versions as you:

```
"styled-components": "^5.3.3",
"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.19",
```

And here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In typescript, the type definition is very important.

**1. theme**

```
import {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components';

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   //Your children component here
</ThemeProvider>
```

for types

```
//./styled-components.d.ts

import themeVariables from '<//theme variables path here>';

type ThemeInterface = typeof themeVariables 

declare module "styled-components" {
  interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeInterface {}
}

//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "includes": ["styled-components.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

After it, you can use the theme in the styled component

```
const SomeStyledComponent = styled.div`
   background-color: ${props => props.theme.backgroundColor};
`
```

**2.`<{ invertedColor: boolean }>` issue**

```
interface SomeComponentProps {
   invertedColor: boolean;
}

const SomeComponent = styled.div<SomeComponentProps>`
  color: ${props => (props.invertedColor ? props.theme.color.white : props.theme.color.dark)}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting color type is correct.

Looks like typescript is not recognizing your declare module. I used same version of styled-components but instead of `styled-components.d.ts`, I created `styled.d.ts` file and I did not have any issue